# does the binary operation have an inverse element and or identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, binary-operations

$a*b = \sqrt{ab} \space a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

It is easy enough to show it is communitive and not associative:

$a*b=\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{ba}=b*a$ thus commutative

$(a*b)*c= \sqrt{ab\sqrt{c}} \neq\sqrt{a\sqrt{bc}}= a*(b*c)$ not associative

to find an identity element I need to find an element $e$ S.T. $a*e =a$ Well if we let $b=a$ then a*b = $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ That follows right?

As for an inverse I need something that gives me back...well im not sure

Comment: To find an identity, you need an element $e$ such that $a \ast e = a$ _for all_ $a$, not just a particular one.

Comment: You need $a*e = a$ for *EVERY* element. If $e=a$ then $a*e = a*a = a$ for *that* $a$ but $b*e = b*a \ne b$ nescessarily.

Comment: You need $\sqrt{\pi\cdot e} = \pi$ and $\sqrt{257\cdot e} = 257$.  It is true that $\sqrt{\pi\cdot \pi} = \pi$ but $\sqrt{257\cdot \pi}\ne 257$.  So $e\ne \pi$.  Also note if $a < 0$ then $\sqrt {a\cdot e} = a < 0$ is impossible.

Comment: What is $(-1) * 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close!

One thing to note is that you must provide a *counterexample* to claim $a * b$ is not asociative. That is, can you provide three actual numbers $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $a*(b*c) \neq (a*b)*c$?

As for the identity, $e$ is not allowed to vary! It must be ONE number so that $a*e = e*a = a$. 
Your argument actually shows that *no* such $e$ exists, since for $a \neq e$, we must have $a*e \neq a$.

Finally, since there is no identity, there is no hope of inverses. This is another reason to want one $e$ which works as an identity for every $a$, if you don't have it, then it's not clear what $a * a^{-1}$ should be.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: So always provide a counter example

Comment: Exactly! If you want to prove "for every blah, P(blah)" is false, the only way to do so is to show that there exists a blah where P(blah) fails